# PHP Form: change table data if errors found

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make my form a little better for a project. There are two issues i would like to alter. 
Firstly, I would like - rather than printing the errors 'firstName;, 'surname', etc - i would like to change the border colour of that particular box to red. I have tried using if(in_array('firstName', $error) and then echoing out a style in the table, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Secondly, I would like to keep the value of the dropdown list 'title' if the form is submitted, but doesn't validate. I thought my code would do that, but it appears now.

Here is my code:

```
<?php  

$checkedMale = $_POST['gender'] == 'Male' ? "checked='checked'" :                    

'';
$checkedFemale  = $_POST['gender'] != 'Male' ? "checked='checked'" :  

'';
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$title =$_POST["title"];


if(isset($_POST["gender"])) {

        $gender = $_POST["gender"];

}

$formValidates = false;

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Register') {

$errors = array();

if ( $_POST['title'] == 'select') {

    $errors[] = 'title';

}

if ( $_POST['firstName'] == '') {

    $errors[] = 'firstname';

}

if ( $_POST['surname'] == '') {

    $errors[] = 'surname';          

}

if ( $_POST['email'] == '') {

    $errors[] = 'email';

       } else {

              if ( ! filter_var          

($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
                      $errors[] = "<p>Please supply a valid e-mail 

address</p>";
                  }
               }

if ( $_POST['address'] == '') {

    $errors[] = 'address';          

}

if (count($errors)== 0) {
    $formValidates = true;
}

}

if ( ! $formValidates) {
// Displays errors 
if (count($errors) > 0 ) {
        echo "\n<ul>";
    foreach ($errors as $error){
        echo "\n\t<li>$error</li>";
    }
    echo "\n<ul>";
}


?>
```

```
    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>Title:</th>
            <td>
                <select name="title" >
                     <option value="select" <?php echo 

(isset($_POST['operator']) && $_POST['operator'] == 'select') ?                  

'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Select</option>
                    <option value="mr" <?php echo 

(isset($_POST['operator']) && $_POST['operator'] == 'mr') ? 

'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Mr</option>
                    <option value="mrs" <?php echo 

(isset($_POST['operator']) && $_POST['operator'] == 'mrs') ? 

'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Mrs</option>
                    <option value="miss" <?php echo 

(isset($_POST['operator']) && $_POST['operator'] == 'miss') ? 

'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Miss</option>
                    <option value="mr" <?php echo 

(isset($_POST['operator']) && $_POST['operator'] == 'dr') ? 

'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Dr</option>                  
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>First name:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName"     

placeholder="First Name..." value="<?php   

if(isset($_POST['firstName'])){echo $_POST['firstName']; } ?>" />   

</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Surname:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="surname" 

placeholder="Surname..." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['surname'])){                         

echo $_POST['surname']; } ?>" /></td>                                
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Email:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail 


Address..." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){    
                     echo $_POST['email']; } ?>"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <td><textarea name="address" placeholder="Postal Address..." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['address'])){                         echo $_POST['address']; } ?>"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Gender:</th>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"      <?php echo $checkedMale?> >Male<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"    <?php echo $checkedFemale?> >Female<br>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td>                        
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='Car' 
                <?php echo in_array('Car',  $_POST['option']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>I have a Car licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='Motorcycle' 
                <?php echo in_array('Motorcycle',   $_POST['option']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>I have a Motorcycle licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='Fishing' 
                <?php echo in_array('Fishing',  $_POST['option']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>I have a Fishing licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='TV' 
                <?php echo in_array('TV',   $_POST['option']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>I have a TV licence<br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='Dog' 
                <?php echo in_array('Dog',  $_POST['option']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>I have a Dog licence<br>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</form> 

<?php } else { 

    ?>
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td>Title:</td><td><?php echo $title ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Name:</td><td><?php echo $firstName ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Surname:</td><td><?php echo $surname ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email:</td><td><?php echo $email ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address:</td><td><?php echo $address ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Gender:</td><td><?php echo $gender ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Licences:</td><td><?php if(!empty($_POST["option"])) { 

  foreach($_POST["option"] as $checked) { echo $checked." Licence".
                        "<br>";}}?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Registration completed: </td> <td><?php echo date("l d/m/y");                   

?> at <?php echo date("h:ia"); ?></td>  
</tr>
</table>

<a href='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>'>BACK</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: then you have to set a red border in the style if the name isn't set. This is an example:

```
<th>First name:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name..."
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) and $_POST['firstName']!=""){
   echo "value='" . $_POST['firstName'] . "'";
   } 
  else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){echo "style='border:2px solid red'";}?>/>
</td>
</tr>
```

On the other question, you almost have the answer in your code. It is just that this `$_POST['operator']` doesn't do anything. If you just change it to the `$title` variable, it works.

```
<option value="mr" <?php echo ($title == 'mr') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Mr</option>
```

Edit: Added additional if-statements in first question, as the first one didn't check if the request was post.

Comment: The title one works! Thank you. I had just copied the code from another script, and forgot to change it. The 'firstName' one isn't quite what i'm after. It seems to set the border as red by default - i.e. if empty, as it is when the page is loaded. I only want the border style to change, if the form has been submitted and the input field is left blank. Do you know how i would do that?

Comment: My fault, I forgot to check if the user actually had submitted the form, and if the `$_POST['firstName']` actually was empty. Try:              `<input type="text" name="firstName"     

placeholder="First Name..." <?php   

if (isset($_POST['firstName']) and $_POST['firstName']!="")              {echo "value='" . $_POST['firstName'] . "'"; }                                       else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")                      {echo "style='border:2px solid red'";}?>/>`

Comment: That work perfectly. The final issue i have is the same, but different fields. With the text area field (address) - I simply get the error message displayed in the input box. Do you know how i'd get around this? I've played around, but i can't get the right answer. I also can't figure it out for the drop down box. How would I go about that one?

Comment: These should work: Address: `<textarea name="address" placeholder="Postal Address..." <?php if(isset($_POST['address']) and $_POST['address']!=""){echo ">" . $_POST['address']; } else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){echo "style='border:2px solid red'>";} else{echo ">";}?></textarea>` and drop down: `<select name="title" <?php   

if((!isset($_POST['title']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") or (isset($_POST['title']) and $_POST['title']=="select")){echo "style='border:2px solid red'"; }?>>`

Comment: You sir, are an absolute legend! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you, but I'm certainly not a legend.